# Min Max in BlueJ

Tags: bluej

I am doing my homework from my uni but I am quite struggling with this question: **Read in integers until the user enters -1. If there were at least 3 values, show the average excluding the biggest and smallest number.**
This is my code but seems like it does not get rid of the biggest and the smallest number to get the average.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MiddleAverage {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum;
        int count;
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        double average;
        sum = 0;
        count = 0;
        average = 0;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Value: ");
        int value = scanner.nextInt();
        while ( value != -1)
        {
            if ( value < min )
            min = value;

            if ( value > max )
            max = value;

            System.out.print("Value: ");
            value = scanner.nextInt();
            count++;
            sum = sum + value;
            average = sum / count;
        }
        if (value == -1)
        {
            System.out.println("Middle average is: " + average);
        }



    }
}
```

Do you have any idea about this please explain to me. Thank you!

Comment: You're keeping track of the `min` and `max` values, but you never do anything with them.  If you want to get rid of them before printing the average, you'll have to write the code that does that.

Comment: Hey thank you for your suggestion. One more question is that the code does that inside the "while" loop or inside the "If" loop. Thank you

Comment: There _is no_ if loop. There are only if statements.

Comment: Sorry I meant "If" statements sorry

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you calculate the average every time a value is entered, this is a bit wasteful as you only need the average at the end.  (and it also makes it hard to remove the min & max!)

I've made a few changes to your code, take a look:

```
int sum = 0, count = 0; // Condensed a few lines

int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE; 
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int value;

System.out.print("Value: ");
value = scanner.nextInt();

while (value != -1) {

    if ( value < min )
        min = value;

    if ( value > max )
        max = value;

    count++;
    sum = sum + value;

    System.out.print("Value: ");
    value = scanner.nextInt();
}

// You don't need to check if it's -1 because it MUST be in order to leave the loop
if (count >= 3) {
    System.out.println("Middle average is: " + (sum - max - min) / (count - 2));
} else {
    // Less then 3 values
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: I hope it helped!  It should be noted that there are a few different ways to do this, I tried to follow what you already had.  Also, don't forget to upvote / accept helpful ;)

Comment: Watch out for integer division - you need to cast one of the `/` operands to a floating-point type or you'll get an integral answer.